# Using Materialized Views for RLS in Supabase: Best Practices and UI Limitations

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

#### Body

Hello everyone,

I'm working on a project where I need to calculate the final cost (`gasto`) for each expense by applying various taxes. I also need to implement Row-Level Security (RLS) to restrict data access based on the user ID.

##### Context:

- I have a table called `gastos` that stores individual expenses.
- I have another table called `taxesValues` that stores different types of taxes.
- A third table, `gastosAppliedTaxes`, establishes a many-to-many relationship between `gastos` and `taxesValues`, indicating which taxes are applied to each expense.
- I initially used a view called `final_gastos` to calculate the final cost (`gasto`) for each expense after applying the taxes. The view essentially joins `gastos`, `taxesValues`, and `gastosAppliedTaxes` to perform this calculation.

##### Why Materialized View?

I opted for a materialized view for two main reasons:

1. **Performance**: Materialized views store the result of the query, making data retrieval faster, especially when dealing with complex joins and calculations.
2. **Row-Level Security (RLS)**: Unlike regular views, materialized views in PostgreSQL allow for the application of RLS policies. This is crucial for my application as I need to restrict data based on the user ID.

##### Questions:

1. **Materialized Views for RLS**:
   Given the above, I switched from using a view to a materialized view called `final_gastos` so that I can apply RLS. Is this a good approach? Are there any downsides or better alternatives?
2. **Supabase UI Limitations**:
   I noticed that the Supabase UI doesn't show policies for materialized views and lacks a UI for setting policies like it does for normal tables. Is this a limitation of Supabase, or am I missing something?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RLS policies are set on tables and not views. When you have a view, the RLS of underlying tables are respected if the view is a security invoker. I believe in Postgres, materialized views do not support RLS at the moment.

You can create a security invoker view like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW .. WITH (security_invoker=on)
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented this in my Supabase project recently and it has worked perfectly so far!